# find elements within radius in a 2d array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, geometry, points

i have a 2d array of tuples representing the xy coordinates of equally spaced points. what i need to do is given a center point coordinates, get all other points within radius. i have found this picture on the internet which sort of demonstrate what i want to achieve only difference is that my array is not random.
[image: 2d array]

i have been using a kdTree to search for items within radius and it works fine but for a lot of points this gets super slow. i have also tried the following but it is also extremely slow

```
 for (int i = 1; i < radius; i++)
 {
 for (int j = 1; j < radius; j++)
 {
     if (i*i + j*j <squaredRadius)
     {
         points.Add(new int[]{i,j});
         points.Add(new int[]{-i,j});
         points.Add(new int[]{i,-j});
         points.Add(new int[]{-i,-j});
     }
  }
}
```

i was if anyone would have any suggestions on a faster way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you a formula like (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2 where (a,b) is coord of the center and r is its radius. Then use (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2<=r^2 to check if (x,y) is with the radius or not.

You can loop all the cell of your array to collect all the value you need or you can use some math to narrow the range of x and y to make the finding process faster.

Comment: i think i have already tried this where i loop through all the cells in one quadrant of the circle and use the squared distance to eliminate cells that are within the quadrant but outside the radius. however, when using this method 100000 times it takes about 6 minutes to finish and i was hoping for something more efficient.

Comment: Did you try to narrow the range of x and y first? In your case, x is in `(-|r+a|,|r+a|)` and y should be in `(-|r+b|,|r+b|)`. This will make the loop significantly faster.

Answer (score 0):

This problem lends itself perfectly for parallel execution. You need to find the boundary of one quadrant then you can spawn 2r threads and do this for each vertical strip or horizontal strip (like a blur image filter). That should speed things up. 
Obviously you will have to bounds check in each thread, think if your center point is corner or edge or close to....

Comment: using the kdtree method and thread pooling i have seen great improvements as now it only takes 1.5 minutes for around 150000 points but, what might be interesting is solving only for 1/4 of the points instead of the whole set

Comment: Yeah and by 2r I mean the number of points on the longest diagonal (7 in the case of the image you posted)